# Bem nested naming

Tags: css, bem

Let's say I have `panel` block with cards inside of it each I want to make block, so it should be something like:

```
.control-block
  .control-panel
    .control-results
      .card
        .card-title
        .card-body
```

Should I use some prefix to `.card` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any prefixes for `card` block but I'd rather go with something like this:

```
.control
  .control__panel
    .control__results
      .card
        .card__title
        .card__body
```

So there's two blocks: `control` with `card` inside of it.
`control` has two elements: `panel` and `results`. And `card` has `title` and `body`.

If you want to connect `card` with `control` you may add a [mix](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix) with `control__card` so the final markup will be:

```
.control
  .control__panel
    .control__results
      .card .control__card
        .card__title
        .card__body
```

For more info about such approach please see https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes